# Hosting a selenium app on GoDaddy. "This program is blocked by group policy"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, selenium, plesk

I have built a standard ASP.NET MVC (.NET 4.52) app and hosted it with GoDaddy on their Plesk hosting.  It calls a class that uses Selenium, I'm using PhantomJS as the web client.

In my services controller that calls the class that references Selenium I get the error:

```
[Win32Exception (0x80004005): This program is blocked by group policy. For more information, contact your system administrator]
   System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo) +1900
   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start() +119
   OpenQA.Selenium.DriverService.Start() +173
```

Others note this fix, but I've already added:

```
<trust level="Full" originUrl="" />
```

This helped for the getting the site up and running, but does nothing for this part of the application.  Perhaps I'm just in a situation where plesk doesnt support this, or perhaps there is another trust level setting or selenium configuration that I'm missing?

Is anyone aware of a way around this error?

Comment: Do you absolutely need to use Selenium/PhantomJS? Can you not accomplish what you want via HTTP requests with something like HttpClient?

Comment: Selenium seems like the right way to do it.  I have to pull info from a site and I get several things for free with Selenium.  Perhaps your point is that I should just pull the HTML and find the dom objects i want myself?

Comment: There are a few steps that I have to go through which made selenium a good choice.  I have to send a value and run a search then collect the results.

Comment: This is all in an effort to QA a site that I control but want automate the way a user would.

Comment: Then why run the Selenium browser in your website? If it's part of the QA process, run it locally against the site.

Comment: Its part of a monitoring system.  It throws a message to a cell phone if it doesnt get the right info.

Comment: I'm willing to entertain the idea that Selenium is not right for this part of the proejct.. but I would first like to figure out that it cannot do what I'm wanting to do.. does that make sense?

Comment: I think that the fact you're getting that error is proof it won't work. GoDaddy is notoriously restrictive. And most hosting providers probably won't want you running random executables (such as Selenium) on their hosts. You typically need to pay for a VM if you want features like that.

Comment: I went the rounds with GoDaddy support and that was the conclusion.  Upgrade to their VPS services.  Thanks @mason for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little help from @mason and going the rounds with GoDaddy support, their solution was to buy their VPS package.

<s>I opted for an Azure App service running a WebJob as detailed here:</s>

http://blog.nultien.rs/nul-tien-blog/azure-webjob-selenium-webdriver-and-browserstack

(Azure webjobs didnt work, here's why)

[Azure WebJobs cannot access "localhost](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#unsupported-frameworks)" and PhantomJS requires localhost to run.

[WebBrowser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser(v=vs.110).aspx) (which is IE based) uses GDI+ so it has similar problems.

I have moved to a VM solution.