# How to fix error while trying to download pdf

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf-generation

Running my PDF download or opening screen about 2 months ago does not work. As soon as I click the 'Create PDF' button, it gives me the following error. I talked to the server I was working with and they told me that there was no mistake caused by us. When I try local, there is no problem;

> This program is blocked by group policy. For more information, contact your system administrator

[image: ss]

Comment: this is not actually an error per se.  looks like you might need to chat with those in charge of setting group policy.

Comment: @TheGeneral 
because there are no errors in the codes. The output of the code line gives me the error that I specified. so I said it works at the local

Comment: @JohnB the server was on godaddy and they could not help me enough. they say that there is no error caused by them

Comment: Please show us a screenshot of the error so we can see **where** it is occurring.

Comment: how to upload a picture?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: @mjwills 
I added

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hosting a selenium app on GoDaddy. "This program is blocked by group policy"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42120015/hosting-a-selenium-app-on-godaddy-this-program-is-blocked-by-group-policy)

Comment: do I need to buy a vps package?

Answer (score 1):

the directory you used to create PDF is shortage of creation Rights 

go to directory 
Right click -> Properties -> go to security Tab -> and give all rights to IIS user

Comment: then please contact system administrator
<br/>
may be group policy is a name of group which has been set by system administrator , however  i am sure its more of permission policy

Comment: but godaddy manager can not help me because he does not know the solution